# jQuery Vallenato Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am just learning a little bit about jQuery and I came across this accordion script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

//Set The Accordion Content Width
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-    header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');


// The Accordion Effect
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
    $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
    $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
}

else {
    $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
    $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
}
});

return false;
});
```

I really like this version of a jquery accordion but I want to add a feature so that the accordion height is only so large and then the content will have a scroll bar. There's an example on the jquery UI site, but their script is quite a bit different. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to customize it is by using CSS, you can easily find references for increasing height and removing the scroll button. Try www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving .accordian-content no height, but a "max-height: ..." and then make "overflow: scroll"?

For instance, try changing

```
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });
```

to

```
$('.accordian-content').css({'width' : contentwidth, 'max-height' : '...', 'overflow' : 'scroll'});
```

Comment: That works but it adds a vertical and horizontal scrollbar to the collapsed accordion header.